# Use contentEditable for Inline Edit with different types of fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable, inline-editing

I have an app which uses Bootstrap/jQuery UI libraries.

I am now looking at implementing a simple in-line edit functionality...planning to use the HTML5 `contentEditable` property

So say a field is displayed as below;
`Field1: Value1`

Now if the user clicks on `Value1`, the value `Value1` would appear in text box at the same place and on press of enter or blur of field, the value would get replaced.

Now there are multiple such fields on the page. While I know I can implement the `contentEditable` attribute for basic elements/fields like `div`, etc there are some input fields like `date`, dropdown for which I would need in-line editing as well...

So not sure if I can use `contentEditable` for such fields....like the input type `date` field would allow for in-line editing but should show a date picker for in-line edit (I use jQuery UI for this)

I have a `Save` button at the end. So on click of `Save`, all these new values would be sent to the server.

Thus my concern is if I can use in-line editing for the various fields using `contentEditable`  ?

Comment: What's exactly you question? You can do whatever you want, but I don't see any reason why you should use a contentEditable element instead of a normal input element in the way that you have stated your "problem". Providing some working code to show exactly the problem would be great in order to provide you the correct answer.

Comment: Pretty much the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/q/24078740/2209007 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/24115867/2209007 by the same user.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can use in-line editing for those `input` fields.

Keep in mind, that there are some issues when using HTML5 `contentEditable` method:

- In Chromium/Chrome `contentEditable` cannot be edited when nested into draggable (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=170139). Still not fixed in Chrome version 26.0.1384.2.
- In Firefox when clicking on `contentEditable` nested into `draggable`, cursor is always positioned to the start of editable text. Still not fixed in version 18.0.1.
- In Internet Explorer `contentEditable` cannot be applied to the `TABLE`, `COL`, `COLGROUP`, `TBODY`, `TD`, `TFOOT`, `TH`, `THEAD`, and `TR` elements **directly**, a content editable `SPAN`, or `DIV` element can be placed inside the individual table cells (See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533690(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533690%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

A note of security: Users can change the contents of a document when the `contentEditable` property is set to `TRUE`. Using this property incorrectly can compromise the security of your application. Incorrect use of the `contentEditable` property might include not validating user input. If you do not validate user input, a malicious user **can inject control characters or script** that can harm your data. You should take **routine precautions** against displaying unvalidated user input.

Comment: Thanks for that..But can I use contentEditable for fields like date picker (jQuery UI) , drodpdown , etc